# Best image upload for drupal

Tags: image, upload, drupal-7, editor

I am building a very simple site in Drupal-7 there users should be able to edit a page and upload an image to the page (inside the text).
I have played around a bit among editors and modules but I do not think I have found something simple enough. Would appreciate if I could get some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the WYSIWYG with IMCE modules many times and find the setup along with the interface very nice.

What modules have you tried and found you didn't like?

Comment: Just now I have WYSIWG, IMCE and IMCE Wysiwyg API bridge and TinyMCE.
Seems that I need some more to get the possibility in the dialog to upload a local file.

Comment: I think I missed to link the IMCE in the config so now I can browse for a local file.

Comment: Is there any module you recommended to get it easier to resize the image to fit the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Image field in the content type. This way your users will be able to add images. You can specify how many images each post can contain and can be infinite.

The images will show where the text ends. You can play with views to put the images elsewhere.

You can control the position of the images via CSS and sub-themes.

You can also use 
http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_imageupload

(6th result on google searching for 'drupal image upload')